# How to set options using variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I want to set some options with a couple of variables, check below to see the final outcome I want it to be:

```
$("#map").mapmarker({
    center: "-37.788709,175.292750",
});
```

I'm trying to achieve this with these two variables:

```
$("#map").mapmarker({
    center: markers.latitude, markers.longitude,
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work, when I alert the two `latitude` and `longitude` the output is correct.

I think I may have put the two variables with the incorrect code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
center: markers.latitude + ',' + markers.longitude,
```