# Using Variable to Set Configurable Option Javascript

Tags: javascript

I found a very similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503191/how-to-set-options-using-variables), but this is dealing with strings. What I would like to do is set an option with a variable. The code looks like this:

```
carousel.reload({
    startingItem: 5
});
```

Since this is an option with an integer, it's different than the question I linked above. How would I pass a variable into this to mimic the below code?

```
carousel.reload({
    startingItem: array.length
});
```

Comment: What's the problem? That code should work.

Comment: And yes it's the same for numbers as it is with strings.

Comment: I cannot believe I messed that up. Sorry guys. There was a dumb error preventing the use of the variable. Smh...it works as it should.